# Is there any way to reset your default armor?

Tags: spiral-knights

Is there any way to change your starting armor?  For example, I started with a Spiral Sallet with Mecha Wings, and a regular Spiral Armor.  Can I change these to something else? Or are they stuck like that permanently?

Comment: Are you just asking if you can remove accessories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the armor itself, alas, there is currently no way to change your starting proto armor.  However...

> [There will likely be some way in the future for players to acquire costume versions of all the proto sets.](http://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/66572#comment-548513)

If you're referring to the accessories, you cannot change those either.  You may remove them, but they would be destroyed in the process.